# UITableView datasource

Tags: ios, uitableview, datasource

I have a tableview and an array source. When I init array in viewDidLoad method, tableview shows the data in the array. When I fill the array from a URL which is a XML data on the internet, the table gives an error. Because it first runs numberOfRowsInSection function but the array is not ready yet. How can i run table methods after initializing the array which loads data from the internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first return 0 from `numberOfRowsInSection`, until your array is filled, when the array is filled correctly you call `[tableView reloadData];`

Answer (score 0):

When the data has been returned to you, call `reloadData` on the table.  It will respond by calling the datasource methods again.